# Mandar Texto do display de um Enum por Json

Tags: javascript, c#, json, enums

Galera, eu tenho um enum para os dias da semana, sendo:

```
    Segunda = 2,
    [Display(Name="Terça")]
    Terca = 3,
    Quarta = 4,
    Quinta = 5,
    Sexta = 6,
    [Display(Name = "Sábado")]
    Sabado = 7
```

Então eu construo um objeto que tem um dia da semana na `Api`, e eu faço um get json em javascript e mostro na tela usando `knockout`, o problema é que se eu deixar como enum, ele vai mostrar o numero equivalente ao dia, e se eu faço `ToString()` ele mostra o nome normal, sem acentos e sem caracteres especiais, o que eu gostaria de mostrar era o display, existe algum método que faça isso? ou tenho que fazer "na mão"?

Comment: da uma olhada veja se te ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248521/bind-an-enum-to-a-combo-box-using-knockout

Comment: obrigado, mas ele tem um problema diferente...

Comment: então amigo favor demonstrar o erro para podermos ajudar .... precisamos tambem de algo que você já fez para ficar mais facil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um código que retorna o texto do `[Display(Name = "texto"]`, pra quem precisar retornar ele para a tela por javascript ou de algum outro modo.

```
        public static string GetDisplayNameEnum(Enum enumValue)
        {
           var displayName = enumValue.GetType().GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                       .First()
                       .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?
                       .Name;

           return displayName ?? enumValue.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra opção, usando [método de extensão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136913/para-que-usar-m%c3%a9todos-de-extens%c3%a3o-do-c) e o atributo `Description` seria:

**Enum:**

```
public enum Status
{
    [Description("Aguardando Aprovação")]       
    AguardandoAprovacao = 0,

    Aprovado = 1,       
    Recusado = 2        
}
```

**Classe e método de extensão:**

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string DisplayDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Usando:**

```
string textoEnum = Status.AguardandoAprovacao.DisplayDescription()
```

Deixei no [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T3XZQz) para referencia